# How to install redmine backlogs plugin on Heroku

Tags: heroku, redmine

I followed this link

http://mplsalicia.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/redmine-2-1-on-heroku-cedar-with-attachments-on-s3/

and deploy Redmine with redmine_s3 plugin on Heroku successfully, but I don't know how to install redmine backlogs plugin

Any body can help me?

Comment: what problems are you having? the installation guide is here: http://www.redminebacklogs.net/en/installation.html

Comment: @ctshryock: I followed install guide from redminebacklogs.net, I could install backlogs successfully on localhost but I don't know how to install it on heroku.

Comment: is it not as simple as adding the files to your git repo and pushing to heroku?

Answer (score 1):

Redmine Backlogs(plugin for agile team) install guide:

1. Download latest from https://github.com/backlogs/redmine_backlogs
2. Copy under `plugins` directory to have something like this: `plugins/redmine_backlogs`
3. Run `bundle exec rake redmine:backlogs:install`

   - For Heroku you need to run `heroku run rake redmine:backlogs:install`
4. Start Redmine and follow configuration snippets.